# how to let qt msvc2013 make command runnable

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

I don't know how to do this with msvc.
I succeeded when I used mingw.

I have to use make and make install in the command line because I want to use QtXlsxWriter which is a module.

I installed visual studio 2013 and Qt 5.5.1 VS 2013 only

[image]

Comment: Could you please translate the error message to english?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness.
Not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio has `nmake` instead of `make`. You also need Perl. [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) may be used here:

- Start Visual Studio command prompt
- Set the `PATH` variable to point to Perl and Qt binary folders, for example: `PATH=c:\Strawberry\perl\bin;c:\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin;%PATH%`
- go to `QtXlsxWriter` folder
- `qmake`
- `nmake`
- `nmake install`

Comment: @Woody On the first step you should open not regular `cmd`, but `Visual Studio Command Prompt`. It is like `cmd` console with configured VS environment. You can find it in the menu `Programs->Visual Studio 2013->Visual Studio Tools`.

Answer (score 2):

1. <strike>`qmake`: Creates `Makefile` from `qtxlsx.pro`</strike>
2. <strike>`make`: Builds `Makefile`</strike>

---

Bullsit, sorry. There is no `make` in the Windows build system.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `.pro` Qt project file.

1. You can generate a makefile with `qmake` and compile it with `nmake`:

   ```
   qmake
   nmake
   ```
2. You can open it in QtCreator IDE and build from there directly.
3. You can generate Visual Studio IDE project file (`.vcxproj`):

   ```
   qmake -tp vc
   ```

   and

   - either open it in Visual Studio and build from there

   or

   - build it from command line with `msbuild`:

     ```
     msbuild projectname.vcxproj
     ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have succeeded through nmake.